# linuz-linux can't be found in efi-bootmanager on iMac

Tags: arch-linux, boot-loader, uefi

Ive just installed a fresh new instance of arch-linux on my old iMac.
Unfortunately, the apple default efi bootloader isn't be able to load the efi-entry.

My partitions are:

```
#1 EFI
#2 Mac OS X
#3 Rescure Mac
#4 boot (my /boot-partition for linux)
#5 encrypted
```

partition 5 is my enrypted partition, which contains the lvm volume-group which contains 3 partitions (root, home and swap).

I've mounted efi (#1) on /boot/efi. In boot, there is my kernel-image vmlinuz-linux. In /boot/efi/loader/entries/arch-encrypted.conf, I've edited the file so the option "linux" has /vmlinuz-linux. Now it looks like that:

```
title          Arch Linux
linux          /vmlinuz-linux
initrd         /initramfs-linux.img
options        encrypteddevice=UUID=<UUID of partition #5>:lvm root=/dev/mapper/vg--base-lv--root quiet rw
```

But now when Im rebooting my system, arch isn't booting but an error message will get printed containing "*\vmlinuz-linux can't be found*".

I guess this is so because the linux-image is located on an different partition but this efi-entry points to the efi-partition where the entry is located itselv.

Can anybody help me with this please?

Answer (score 2):

You probably answered your own question. The paths in the .conf file are relative to the root of the ESP, and no other partitions are known at this stage. `vmlinuz-linux` (et al.) are put in `/boot` by pacman, and if `/boot/efi` (the ESP) is mounted under /boot they are on different partitions.

You could merge the partitions so that the ESP is mounted on `boot`. For other solutions, see [EFI System Partition](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/EFI_System_Partition).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So would it be possible to format the /boot-partition as vfat/fat32 so that efi could get installed as well as the linux boot images?

Comment: [This article](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/) and [several others](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) at Rod's excellent site might help you understand what's going on.

Comment: Yes, you can of course re-format the /boot partition, but even simpler is to move the files in /boot to your ESP and mount that partition as /boot.